# Virtual Machine Middle Mouse Click

Tags: virtualbox, mouse, touchpad

I have tried searching and cannot find a definitive answer.

The base problem is that when running ubuntu on a virtual machine, I cannot find a way to get the middle mouse button to work while using a trackpad on a Dell XPS 13.

I have tried to use drivers, which don't work, since it's a virtual machine, among other methods. the only thing I have gotten to work is by remapping the right click to be the middle mouse click. Which now doesn't work because of the upgrade of X11 to Wayland.

My question is, does somebody either have a solution with the base issue of getting the middle mouse to work while using a trackpad via a virtual machine. Or have a solution with getting xinput to work with Wayland, the error message i get now is:

> WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.

Using libinput the error message I get when listing devices for example is

> libinput-list-devices: Command not found.

Using gnome-tweak-tool doesn't work either since a virtual machine doesn't have access to the trackpad directly.

I'd appreciate any help, thank you in advance.